# approximate variance of the area of a randomly generated triangle using simulations in R

Tags: r, simulation

If two sides of a triangle (a and b) and their angle (γ) is known, one can calculate the area of the triangle with

```
area = (1/2)*ab*sin(γ)
```

Using simulations find the approximate variance of the area of a randomly generated triangle, with the parameters having following distributions:

```
 a ~ Gamma(shape=11, rate=6)
 b ~ Gamma(shape=24, rate=18)
 γ ~ Uniform(1, π/2)
```

I am quite stuck and don't really know how to proceed. I have tried

```
 rgamma(n, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate)
```

however I do not clearly see how to connect a,b and γ together and how to calculate the variance out the the area.

Comment: I think that formula at the top i how you connect a, b, and y together to get the area. And `var` is how you calculate the variance. What do you have so far? Maybe you could write a function for the area? In valid R syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Define a function that would calculate area
tri.area <- function(a, b, gamma){
  return(0.5*a*b*sin(gamma) )
}

# Number of random triangles to construct
N <- 100

# create randomly distributed vectors with given distributioin
a.vector <- rgamma(N, shape=11, rate=6)
b.vector <- rgamma(N, shape=14, rate=8)
gamma.vector <- runif(N, min=1, max=pi/2)

# calculate vector of areas for each triple of values
tri.area.vec <- tri.area (a.vector, b.vector, gamma.vector)

# find variance
var(tri.area.vec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it! :) I was struggling a lot with this question!

Comment: You are welcome. If this is what you are looking for - accept the solution.